# Saving data to a variable that has been read from an excel file

Tags: c#

I have written a code in c sharp. It is a console application. I have an excel file with some numeric data. My application reads the excel file and displays the data in each cell via a message box. For example, if the 1st cell data is 5, the message box displays 5. When I click Ok button in the message box, the message box displays the next data from the next cell.

I wish for the read data from the excel file to be saved in some sort of variables so that it can be used for further operations such as addition or multiplication or anything as per the requirement. How do I do so? Any help will be of great help.

Posting my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:/A.xlsx");
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;
            for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to do it is to create a class something like this

```
public class MyData
{
    public int column { get; set; }
    public int row { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }

}


 List<MyData> listdata = new List<MyData>();
         for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
                {
                    MyData mdata = new MyData();
                    MessageBox.Show(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString());
                    mdata.column=j;
                    mdata.row=i;
                    mdata.data=xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString();
                    listdata.Add(mdata);
                }
            }
```

And then you can search thru the list and find the specific value you want based on row column

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a collection of types of type or you may have to write custom type as in a class that can hold data you want to read from excel.

In the for loop, instantiate the collection or custom type, read data and feed into collection/custom type.

Comment: can u help me with any code for this? Kinda new to this collections and custom types. If u wish.

Comment: see... you know how many columns are there in your excel sheet per row
so create a class with that many member
and create a generic list of that class
in for loop create a new instance of class
assign values from excel sheet to object's variables
and then add it to the list